# How to convert mysql query to django orm

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to execute this query, it's working fine in MySQL workbench, but It's not working in python shell.[image]

And I have to export that result in an Excel sheet.

Comment: Please post all that as text here, not as screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

As de error suggests the SELECT clause must contain the primary key in order to be able to build the ORM object. By default, the primary key is a column named pk. I advise using "SELECT *" in this case if possible, maybe the "AS" could give problems too.